# adb: error: failed to get feature set: more than one device/emulator

Tags: android, adb

incus@mini:~/Desktop$ adb kill-server
incus@mini:~/Desktop$ adb devices

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully
  List of devices attached
  HT7AV1A00699    unauthorized

idk what this device is, how can i disconnect from it ?

ive tried rebooting, ive tried adb kill-all adb disconnect idk what else to try

incus@mini:~$ adb kill-server&&adb start-server

- daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
- daemon started successfully
  incus@mini:~$ adb devices
  List of devices attached
  HT7AV1A00699    unauthorized

incus@mini:~$ adb disconnect
disconnected everything
incus@mini:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
HT7AV1A00699    unauthorized

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit the help center, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Your question need some formating, see [Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: When the device is connected run `adb devices -l` and you'll get more info.